# javascript onclick call a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found that code on internet and it works fine to create a button

```
  document.write(nomedispositivo)
  var r=$('<input/>').attr({//início botão
  type: "button",
  id: "field" ,
  value: "Liga",
```

But if I insert the line:   onclick:switchLED() where switchLED is a function the button not appear where is the problem?

```
  document.write(nomedispositivo)
  var r=$('<input/>').attr({//início botão
  type: "button",
  id: "field" ,
  value: "Liga",
  onclick:switchLED()
```

Comment: You are executing a function and pass the result value to the onclick, you should pass it as string: `onclick:"switchLED()"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why add the click handler this way in the first place?  You're using jQuery, so use jQuery.  Just add the handler to the jQuery element you already have:

```
var r=$('<input/>').attr({
  type: "button",
  id: "field" ,
  value: "Liga"
});

r.click(switchLED);
```

Since `r` is a jQuery element, you can use the `click(function)` function to add a function reference to that element's click event handler.